# Django LDAP - Unable to BIND Successful Connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, ldap

I am trying to establish LDAP Authentication on my Django Project.

I am extremely new to all these things, and unable to find any documentation or helpful video or answers anything related to this.

After making the below changes in my settings.py I am trying to login to Django admin panel and it says that I am providing invalid credentials.

However I am still able to login via my credentials of mariadb. which is root/root.

NOTE: To hide the sensitive information, I am adding all the sensitive information under `% %`
And while I provide my LDAP credentials, the console throws this error:

```
result(5) raised OPERATIONS_ERROR({'msgtype': 101, 'msgid': 5, 'result': 1, 'desc': 'Operations error', 'ctrls': [], 'info': '000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C09075A, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1'},)
search_s('OU=%ou%, DC=%dc% , DC=%dc%', 2, '(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)') returned 0 objects:
Authentication failed for %myusername%@%domain%.com: failed to map the username to a DN.
```

I have the following LDAP configuration settings provided by my administrator peoples. This is stored in a file and they do point to it for all the LDAP configs:

```
   AuthType Basic
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://%domain.abc.lan%/OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,DC=%dc%,DC=%dc%?sAMAccountName?sub"
   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=%cn% ,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,DC=%dc%,DC=%dc%"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "%password%"
   AuthLDAPGroupAttribute  %attribute%
   AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
```

Now, I am extremely confused on how can I make use of all this data.

This is what my settings.py looks like:
I have provided `AuthLDAPBindPassword`  and `Auth_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD` both because one of them is provided by my organisation and one is provided by LDAP and I am extremely confused what can be used and similarly with the BIND DN.

```
from pathlib import Path
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, LDAPSearchUnion, GroupOfNamesType
import os
from ldap import OPT_REFERRALS, SCOPE_SUBTREE
SITE_ID =1


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
)

AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = False

LOGGING = {
"version": 1,
"disable_existing_loggers": False,
"handlers": {"console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler"}},
"loggers": {"django_auth_ldap": {"level": "DEBUG", "handlers": ["console"]}},
}

AuthLDAPBindDN = "CN=Ldap Account,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,DC=%dc%,DC=%dc%"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=Ldap Account,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,OU=%ou%,DC=%dc%,DC=%dc%"
Auth_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "%password%"
AuthLDAPBindPassword = "%password%"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
"username": "sAMAccountName",
"first_name": "givenName",
"last_name": "sn",
"email": "mail",
}   

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearchUnion(

LDAPSearch("OU=%ou%, DC=%dc%, DC=%dc%", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"),
LDAPSearch("OU=%ou%, DC=%dc%, DC=%dc%", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"),
LDAPSearch("OU=%ou%, DC=%dc%, DC=%dc%", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"),
LDAPSearch("OU=%ou%, DC=%dc%, DC=%dc%", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"),

)

AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {OPT_REFERRALS: 0}
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://%url%:389"
```

I will be really glad to get this thing sorted as I am trying to get this done from last 24 hours and I have no clue what's stopping it from establishing the connection.

Comment: Maybe try to lose all those %'s. I don't see them anywhere in other examples.

Comment: Thanks for responding @EPaul , Are you talking about removing the `s` present in `(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)` ?

Comment: No, the `%` ....

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion @EPaul , Actually I added that %%in stack overflow only to hide the sensitive information. 
I added a note to the question now. 
Do you have any idea on how can we check if bind is working or not via command prompt ?

Comment: You can use [`ldapsearch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) from the command line to test your credentials. Where is your code (where the binding occurs) ? Is your ldap backend an Active Directory ?